# Freemarker: Expression is undefined

Tags: freemarker

I have this code:

```
[#list doc.presidents as president][#if president.name?has_content]${president.name}[/#if][/#list]
```

When I run it, I have the error: `Expression president is undefined`.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have a `null` in that `presidents` list.

As of the nested content of `#list`, it could be just written as `${president.name!}`. If you expect the `president` itself to be `null`, then `${(president.name)!}`.